# Mitzvah habaah beaveirah with a rabbinic prohibition

Tags: halacha-theory, mitzvah, sin

Is fulfilling a biblical mitzvah by transgressing a rabbinic prohibition considered "mitzvah habaah beaveirah", where they lose their credit for the mitzvah (see [Sukkah 30a](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sukkah.30a.1))? For instance returning a lost object which is a muktzah on shabbat, or a man doing pru urvu without marriage etc?

Comment: "or a man doing pru urvu without marriage" not sure how this is derabanan. Isn't it at least a bittul aseh?

Comment: Also pru urvu is a bad example for mitzvah habaah beaveirah. See minchas Chinuch mitzvah 1

Answer (score 6):

The [Shaar Hamelech in Hilchos Lulav 8:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Shofar%2C_Sukkah_and_Lulav.8.1?lang=bi&p2=Sha%27ar_HaMelekh_on_Mishneh_Torah%2C_Shofar%2C_Sukkah_and_Lulav.8.1.1&lang2=bi) (paragraph starting with V’Dah Shezeh) addresses this exact question and proves from [Rashi in Pesachim 35b](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.35b.11?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Pesachim.35b.11.1&lang2=b) that even an issur drabbanan is also enough to make it a mitzvah habah baeveira

> ואולם מטעם אחר היה נראה דאינו יוצא בו י"ח משום דה"ל מה"ב והיה מקום לצדד ולומר דמשום מה"ב לא מיפסיל אלא בעבירה דאוריי' אמנם בעבירה דרבנן לא מיפסיל משום מה"ב אולם מצאתי לרש"י שכתב בפ' כ"ש דל"ה ע"ב וז"ל טבול מדרבנן ואפ"ה מה"ב היא חשיב לה ע"ש וכ"כ שם לעיל בד"ה ודמאי לא חזי ליה כו' א"נ הויא לי' מה"ב ע"ש וא"נ ה"נ דכוותא אע"ג דאינו אלא איסורא דרבנן חשיב מה"ב כנ"ל ועוד יש בזה אריכות דברים לא עת האסף פה ודעת הר"ן כדעת התוס